# How can I update the suggestions in to XML-view?

Tags: eclipse, sapui5

I see that there is a new version (1.22) of UI5 API.
Before I used the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut to suggest the element to insert into a XMLView. How can I update the suggestions?

For example, I want to insert [sap.m.DatePicker](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.DatePicker) but Eclipse doesn't show it.

[image: Screenshot in Eclipse for UI5]

I used [this guide](https://openui5.blogspot.com/p/ide.html) to configure Eclipse few weeks ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your Eclipse Tools and you'll have the latest SAPUI5 version.

[image: Installing/Updating SAPUI5 Tools]

If you need a special version you could try by adding the js-files as a User Library via Window > Preferences > JavaScript > Include Path > User Library > Import...

GL

Comment: The newest version I see in the plugins is 1.20.11 :/ You also find the libraries in Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries. But since they are packaged as .jars it could get tricky to update those manually...